# Implement a Dependency property in a custom object

Tags: .net, dependency-properties

1) I have custom

```
Class Foo
End Class
```

Can I implement on it a Dependency property?

2) I have a custom

```
Class Bar
    Inherits NonDependencyObjectBase
End Class
```

Can I implement on it a Dependency property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, however you can implement an attached property in non dependency object.

Comment: attached properties are also for a UIelement or stuff...
Say, if I have an custom third party WinForm control that does not inherit UIElement, I can't extend it with a Dependency, nor attached property?

Comment: yes, it is only for DependencyObject, however we can create attached properties on class that may not be dependency object, for winform based controls you should use INotifyPropertyChanged architecture